# How to run Appium script in multiple Android device/emulators?

Tags: android, python, python-appium

I am trying Appium using Python language. I have written a simple Login script in Python,it executes perfectly in one android device/emultor using Appium. But i have no idea how to run in multiple device/emulators..i read some forums but did not get any solutions(i am very new to Automation-Appium).

Please help me with detailed steps or procedure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create multiple Udid and modify the same in the code.Inorder to launch in multiple devices you need to create multiple instances of appium server opening in Different ports(eg.4000,4001....etc)